# Refresh tables in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-express

How can I refresh the tab in Visual Studio for a database table? Currently I re-open the table but I would think there is a way to refresh the table. I am referring to tables opened via the Server Explorer/SQL Express.

The clear results does not seem to refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a red '**!**' icon on the tool bar. Click that?